# Does anyone know who answers.ninja is?

Tags: discussion

They seem to be violating the licensing on the site and stealing our content.

http://parenting.life.answers.ninja/post/574

[Does anyone recognize where the phrase "Dinosaur on the button" comes from?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/574/does-anyone-recognize-where-the-phrase-dinosaur-on-the-button-comes-from)

Note the footer at the bottom claiming copyright.

Comment: Domain is down, case closed.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a SCRAPER to me.

I've reported it to StackExchange staff.  In the future, feel free to either post here or to do so directly yourself:
[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

Basically it's just: use the [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link, submit the URL of the fraudulent question, the URL of the real question, and any additional information such as the search term that you used to find the question (particularly if it shows up higher than the original page in the Google search).

Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: Ayup, it's a scraper alright. Bottom feeders gonna bottom feed. Pops will get after 'em to comply with our attribution guidelines, thanks!

Comment: I feel sorry for them already.  (Not.  But Pops can be scary...)

Comment: The super-pathetic thing about some scrapers is they get high rankings for the questions I have and when I get there am only frustrated that the structure of the scraped site is so far removed from the quality of SE!  One can only hope that they realize that imitation-via-theft is not flattery! Grrr!

Comment: wow, I didn't even realize that was a thing. :(

Comment: @cabbey Well, SO/SE do permit sites to repackage their content - as long as they follow CC BY-SA-With Attribution.  There are sites that follow this, and are fine; they largely grab the SE data dump and use that for their own database.  Then there are these kinds of sites...